# skaffold + helm integration

Tags: kubernetes-helm, skaffold

I am trying to play around with `skaffold` and `helm` for an internal project. Before I ask the actual question I have, here is the `skaffold.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta17
kind: Config
build:
  tagPolicy:
    gitCommit: {}
  artifacts:
    - image: my-image
      custom:
        buildCommand: ./build.sh
  local:
    useDockerCLI: false
    useBuildkit: false
    push: false


deploy:
  helm:
    releases:
      - name: config-map-it
        chartPath: src/main/helm
        artifactOverrides:
          # skaffold will override this with a different tag
          image: my-image
        valuesFiles:
          - src/main/helm/values.yaml
        wait: true
        setValues:
          namespace: my-namespace
```

As you might notice I have a custom way to build the image. It's actually multiple steps, but eventually it does something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# build jar only, no tests, no chart
gradle clean build -x test -x helmChartBuild --quiet

#  ... more steps here    
docker build --build-arg JAR_FILE='build/libs/*.jar'  -t ${IMAGE} .

# load docker image into kind 
kind load docker-image ${IMAGE} --name my-namespace
```

Specifically, notice `${IMAGE}`. I need this, because I am going to invoke :

```
skaffold build
skaffold deploy
```

(and yes, this is how I need it for other unrelated reasons)

So, I invoke `skaffold build` first. I get an image like:

```
myimage/a3eadcc-dirty
```

The next step : `skaffold deploy` will fail with:

```
no tag provided for image [my-image]
```

I understand why and I slightly change the commands now:

```
skaffold build --file-output=tag.json
kind load docker-image ${IMAGE} --name my-namespace
skaffold deploy -a tag.json
```

Unfortunately, this will not work either.

The problem is that `${IMAGE}` is going to be `myimage/a3eadcc-dirty`, while `tag.json` is going to contain the `sha` of the image as the tag, so `deploy` will fail because such an image can not be found.

The solution in my case would not be complicated to be fair. Just parse `${IMAGE}`, find out the tag:

```
export MY_TAG=...
```

and use that with `skaffold deploy --image`...

The question is, is this the way?

Comment: I'm rather mystified as to what's going on here.  Could you explain why you're explicitly loading the image into kind? And re: "`deploy` will fail because such an image can not be found" — why won't the image be found?

Comment: @BriandeAlwis its me to blame for the fact that you are mystified. 1) "Could you explain why you're explicitly loading the image into kind" - I plan to statically validate the k8s manifests, before building the image. So I do : "validate, build, load into kind". It made sense to me when I thought about it... I might be wrong. 2) "deploy will fail because such an image can not be found" - the image that ends up loaded into kind is `123-dirty`, the image that is tried to be loaded by the manifest is the one with `sha` as a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you seem to have a couple of issue: how do you determine the image tags?  How do you test the images and manifests?

You can use `skaffold build --tag xxx` to override the tag policy and build the images with a fixed tag name.

Rather than try to run tests as part of your build, which will greatly slow down your normal development loop, use Skaffold's testing phase.  You can run image tests with the `skaffold test` ([docs](https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/testers/)).  The *custom test* allows running arbitrary commands.  You can run manifest validations as part of this test phase.

With Helm in the picture, you need to *render* (or *hydrate*) the manifests before you can validate them.  You could `skaffold build --file-output images.json && skaffold render --build-artifacts=images.json > manifests.yaml && validate manifests.yaml`.

If your manifest validator expects to retrieve the images, but cannot retrieve images from the local Docker daemon, then you could instead build to a private registry. You can create a temp registry with the `registry:2` image; the temp registry also helps ensure that the images don't escape.

Comment: thank you, this was helpful. What I ended up doing was `skaffold build --file-output=tag.json
  deploy_tag="$(cat tag.json | jq '.builds[].tag' | cut -d '"' -f 2)"
  kind load docker-image "${deploy_tag}" --name spring-k8s
  skaffold deploy -a tag.json`.

Comment: it's a bit counter-intuitive the amount of "dance" that I have to do to make skaffold behave like I want it; but it is most probably because I do not entirely get it. For example, `skaffold delete` does not remove docker images it has just created. I have to do it by hand - and there are many other little tiny things like this that make me scratch my head twice. It's probably a great tool, but I fail to discover its beauty yet.

Comment: We have an uncoming feature called `hooks` that may some parts of this easier for you <https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/1441>. I still don't understand why you are manually loading the image into `kind`?  Just to be clear: Skaffold will automatically load your image into `kind` as part of the `skaffold deploy`.  BTW: `skaffold run` combines `skaffold build` and `skaffold deploy`.

Comment: ok, so may be I entirely miss something. [how about this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68414470/scaffold-miss-configuration-or-how-to-set-up-a-simple-helm-example)?