# skaffold miss configuration or how to set up a simple helm example

Tags: skaffold, cicd

I am a bit puzzled how to set-up `skaffold` correctly in my case. Here is my `skaffold.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta17
kind: Config
build:
  tagPolicy:
    gitCommit: {}
  artifacts:
    - image: zero-x/spring-cloud-kubernetes/config-map-it
      custom:
        buildCommand: ./build.sh
  local:
    useDockerCLI: false
    useBuildkit: false
    push: false


deploy:
  helm:
    releases:
      - name: config-map-it
        chartPath: src/main/helm
        artifactOverrides:
          # skaffold will override this with a different tag
          image: zero-x/spring-cloud-kubernetes/config-map-it
        valuesFiles:
          - src/main/helm/values.yaml
        wait: true
        setValues:
          namespace: spring-k8s
```

In `build.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# build jar only, no tests, no chart
.././gradlew clean build bootjar -x test -x helmChartBuild --quiet
docker build --quiet --build-arg JAR_FILE='build/libs/*.jar'  -t ${IMAGE} .
```

`${IMAGE}` is provided by `skaffold`.

So I need to build the `jar` first, pack that into an image and deploy. I invoke two things, one after another:

```
skaffold build // builds the image just fine
skaffold deploy
```

fails with :

```
 You either need to:
 run [skaffold deploy] with [--images TAG] for each pre-built artifact
 or [skaffold run] instead, to let Skaffold build, tag and deploy artifacts.
 no tag provided for image [zero-x/spring-cloud-kubernetes/config-map-it]
```

What is going on here? Without much bash-ing, I can't get this one working. The tutorials and documentation about skaffold and how to properly do things, are scarce, to say the least.

**EDIT**

So I was indeed doing:

```
kind create cluster --name spring-k8s --wait 5m
```

To that extent I thought that if I do :

```
deploy:
   kubeContext: kind-spring-k8s
   helm:
   ...
```

things would work, but they do not.

If I start everything from scratch again and run:

```
skaffold deploy --file-output=images.json -vdebug
```

I do see that:

```
Tags used in deployment:
 - zero-x/spring-cloud-kubernetes/config-map-it -> zero-x/spring-cloud-kubernetes/config-map-it:78da248b669d2fafacbd144cf22d7251dfde57c664c70a5fd7d53793d9d5efd7
DEBU[0000] Local images can't be referenced by digest.
They are tagged and referenced by a unique, local only, tag instead.
See https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/taggers/#how-tagging-works
```

Or later:

```
helm --kube-context kind-spring-k8s dep build src/main/helm
```

So this is rather confusing. What *more* am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You need to communicate the images built by `skaffold build` into `skaffold deploy`:

```
skaffold build --file-output=images.json
skaffold deploy --build-artifacts=images.json
```

`skaffold deploy` doesn't (re)build images: it just deploys a set of images.  So `deploy` needs to know the images to be deployed.

`skaffold run` combines these steps into a single command.

Comment: I am really, really glad you came here. after doing the _exact_ `build/deploy` commands, I get : `Helm release config-map-it not installed. Installing...` which never ends. So, I issue : `kubectl get events -n spring-k8s` and as a result : `Failed to pull image "zero-x/spring-cloud-kubernetes/config-map-it:22952eb842cd392409d4fdeb318668338f83f5407ef5d3d48a3d1bd5d27a5b76"`... ok. How about `docker ps` : find the `spring-k8s-control-plane`, exec into it : `docker exec -it spring-k8s-control-plane bash`  and do `crictl images` surprise! the image is simply not here.

Comment: that is the reason, I ended up doing: `skaffold_it() {
  chmod +x build.sh;
  skaffold build --file-output=images.json;
  deploy_tag="$(cat images.json | jq '.builds[].tag' | cut -d '"' -f 2)";
  kind load docker-image "${deploy_tag}" --name spring-k8s;
  skaffold deploy -a images.json;
  cd ..
}`

Comment: Skaffold should be detecting that you’re deploying to `kind` and use ` kind image load ` automagically, but it sounds like that doesn’t seem to be happening. Skaffold detects a kind cluster by the context name: what is your context name?

Comment: Drop the `--name` when creating the kind cluster. `kind` *currently* creates a context of the name `kubernetes-admin@<cluster-name>` (it used different names in the past).  If no cluster name is specified, then the cluster name defaults to `kind`.  Unfortunately there is no robust way to determine if a cluster is a Kind cluster beyond checking its name, which we expect to either begin or end with `kind`.

Comment: I should have said that I have already tried that, with the same result. Do you think if I provide a sample GitHub repo where this is reproducible, it would be helpful?

Comment: Yeah a tiny example would be helpful

Comment: let me know if you need anything more from me. [here is the sample repo](https://github.com/wind57/skaffold-demo)

Comment: You can ignore the debug-level message `Local images can't be referenced by digest.`: it's explaining why its using an image tag instead of an image digest. It may be more confusing than helpful.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce what you're seeing with kind 0.9.0. It seems the `kind load docker-image --name kind zero-x/spring-cloud-kubernetes/config-map-it:xxx` is loading but prefixing the image with `docker.io`. So when the kind cluster looks through its local images for `zero-x/...` it fails and tries to pull the image. I'll have to look into this some more.

Comment: do you happen to have any update on this? thank you!